# I'm using ElasticSearch 8.7.0, but I can't resolve the update error

Tags: elasticsearch

I received a failure response when updating in ElasticSearch 8.7.0, but I don't know the solution.

It was created with the following sentence.

curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/classes/_doc/1  -H "Content-Type: application/json"  -d '{"title":"Algrithm", "professor":"John"}'

When I searched, I got good results.

curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/classes/_doc/1?pretty

{
"_index" : "classes",
"_id" : "1",
"_version" : 7,
"_seq_no" : 7,
"_primary_term" : 2,
"found" : true,
"_source" : {
"title" : "Algrithm",
"professor" : "John"
}
}

I wanted to add credits here, so I updated it, but I received a failure response.

curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/classes/_doc/1/_update?pretty -H'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"doc":{"unit":1}}'

**{
"error" : "no handler found for uri [/classes/_doc/1/_update?pretty] and method [POST]"
}**

Experts, please help...
I want to solve this and sleep~~~

Experts, please help...
I want to solve this and sleep~~~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run your [update](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html) like this:

```
                                       _update goes here
                                             |
                                             v
curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/classes/_update/1?pretty -H'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"doc":{"unit":1}}'
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I finally solved it and am able to continue my studies. 
Have a nice day.

Comment: Cool, glad it helped!